# setting text next to Image at top

Tags: html, css, text-alignment

I have the following HTML (generated by JSF)

```
    <div align="center">
        <img src="images/background_image.jpg" height="200px" width="30%" style="vertical-align: top"/>
        <span style="">
            Welcome abc, <input type="submit" value="logout" />.
            <br />
            Thu, 12-Jul-2012 15:46:07 AST
        </span>
    </div>
```

I was expecting "Thu, 12-Jul-2012 15:46:07 AST" should be next to Image, however I am getting it below image.

I am getting Welcome abc and logout button at the right side of the image.

Can someone point what I am doing wrong?

---

### Edit 1

1. I have used `<div align="center">` just to put everything at the center.
2. If I remove `<br />` tag, I get output as `Welcome abc, logout.Thu, 12-Jul-2012 15:46:07 AST`. If I add `<br />` tag I was expecting output as

   `Welcome abc, logout.`

   `Thu, 12-Jul-2012 15:46:07 AST`

   However because of `<br />` tag I am getting output below image.

Hope this explanation helps.

I am going mad with this :(

---

### Edit 2

### [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a2YJc/1/)

Comment: Here http://jsfiddle.net/ add your code so that we can tweak

Comment: you need to give absolute path for images - http://jsfiddle.net/a2YJc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. Code should be

```
<div align="center">
    <img src="http://blog.kevinchisholm.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/jquery2.png" style="vertical-align: top"/>
    <span style="display:inline-block" align="right">
        Welcome abc, logout.
        <br />
    Thu, 12-Jul-2012 15:46:07 AST
    </span>
</div>
```

### [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a2YJc/2/)

Answer (score 1):

First of all the first div will need to be wide enough to accomodate your image and your span with its text and also set it to overflow:auto to allow floating elemts within it.

You should then float the image and the span to the left.

The span should be set to "display:inline-block".

You'll probably want to give the image some "margin-right".

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to "float" your image and span:

```
img, span {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the text in your span is too long.
in this case you might define your span width to 70%, if it haven't border of course.

Comment: that is not the case. Text I have is `Thu, 12-Jul-2012 15:46:07 AST`